# JDialog lets main application lose focus

Tags: java, swing

I wonder why my JDialog pushes my main application into background. That means if the JDialog will be shown and the user clicks "OK" or "CANCEL" the main application looses its focus and will be pushed into the background.

After my investigation I found out, that this behaviour only happens if I disable my main frame for the time I show the JDialog.

This behaviour could be reproduced with the following code:

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
```

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class FocusTest {

```
private JFrame frame;

public FocusTest() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(200,200);
    JButton btn = new JButton("Open Dialog");
    btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            callDialog(null, "title", "message");
        }
    });
    frame.add(btn);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

private void callDialog(Component parent, String title, String message) {
    frame.setEnabled(false);
    Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            JOptionPane optionPane = new JOptionPane("",
                    JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
                JDialog dialog = optionPane.createDialog(null, "");
                dialog.setVisible(true);
                frame.setEnabled(true);
        }
    });
    t1.start();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new FocusTest();
}
```

}

How can I avoid that the main application looses its focus? (without enabling the main frame)

Comment: I dont see why you would need to open the dialog in a separate thread though. Better to do it on the EDT I'd say.

Comment: The above code is just for a better understanding and reproducing of my problem. My real application does a long running operation in the thread.

Answer (score 5):

You can set the following options to an JDialog class

```
//setUndecorated(true);
setFocusableWindowState(false);
setFocusable(false);
```

For this you can ceate your own JDialog class. You only have to extend from JDialog and put the code into the Constructor call.

Comment: Thanks! This works. After JDialog is shown my main JFrame does not lose focus and still receives key events.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want a simple model dialog (i.e. a dialog which pops up and doesn't allow the user to do anything else until it's closed).  Java makes this really easy - just use JOptionPane's static methods to create the dialog you want.

Try replacing the callDialog function body with:

```
int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frame, message, title,
               JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
```

You'll have a yes/no dialog box appear over the frame which doesn't allow you to do anything with the frame until the user clicks on Yes or No.

If that doesn't meet your needs, try a call to `frame.toFront()` and that will bring the `JFrame` back into the foreground.