# removing focus from JDialog if main application is minimised

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

I have a JDialog which popup whenever my main application recieves an event.
The problem I'm facing is that the dialog pops up evenif the main window is minimised. A similar question was asked here but no answer was given as to how to solve this except a link to sun's guide on focus handling [Hide JDialog window when the window lost focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109148/hide-jdialog-window-when-the-window-lost-focus).
Suppose I have the function createandshowDialog() such as

```
public void createAndShowDialog(boolean manualLaunch) {
        if (manualLaunch || shouldShowMessage()) {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {                        
                        if (dialog == null) {
                            dialog = new xyzDialog(getPendingList());
                        }
                        GUIHelper.flash(PLAFHelper.getMainFrame(), true, false);
                        dialog.setVisible(true);
                   }
                });
            }
}
```

And the xyzDialog class is defined as :

```
  public class xyzDialog extends SimpleStandardDialog
  {
    protected final static Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(xyzDialog.class);

    private xyzPanel panel;

   public xyzDialog(ObjectArrayList list) {
        super(PLAFHelper.getMainFrame(), "Pending Cancel/Replace");
        initializeLocalVars();
        panel = new xyzPanel(list, mediator);
        super.setSize(750,600);
        setResizable(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        setModal(false);//todo: for testing...

        if(PUMAGUIOptions.cFocusOnxyzPopup){
            setFocusableWindowState(true);
            validate();
        }
        else{
            setFocusableWindowState(false);
            validate();

        }

    }
```

The default behaviour should be such that it should not popup if main window is minimised or we explicitly set cFocusOnxyzPopup as false to force this default behaviour (which is the case when it is open on say secondary monitor and we are working on primary monitor or application is maximised or is in background i.e. is not the focusOwner.
I have set focusableWindowState as false so that it would not satisy the condition for gaining focus and return isFocusable as false if invoked as given in java-docs. But this is not working. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

USe JFrame's method

```
public synchronized int getExtendedState()

e.g. PLAFHelper.getMainFrame().getExtendedState()
```

if it's JFrame.ICONIFIED skip the dialog opening.

Comment: but I also want the dialog to show in main application window if the user opens/maximizes/brings to foreground the main application window

Comment: Add WindowStateListener and check whether state is changed.

Comment: ok so if state changed to maximize then show dialog....will test this tomorrow and report the results back here.

Comment: didn't work. The dialog seems to disappear completely if the window is iconified and then I maximize it. In this case, any dialog which might have popped up while the window was iconified should be visible once I open the application window.

Answer (score 1):

I have meet the same problem and search the stackoverflow ! finally, I find out the

corrent answer answered by Markus Lausberg in 
[JDialog lets main application lose focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/823795/jdialog-lets-main-application-lose-focus)

just calling the following method during dialog create:

setFocusableWindowState(false);
setFocusable(false);